# recorrer un array de objetos y guardar propiedades en un nuevo objeto

Tags: javascript, array, poo, bucle-for, javascript-objeto

Tengo un array de objetos de esta forma `[{}, {}, {}]`

Cada objeto tiene las siguientes propiedades

- titulo
- director
- url
- muuuuchas otras propiedades que no necesito para el nuevo objeto (por eso tengo que recorrer hasta encontrar especificamente esas props)

Necesito recorrer el array completo y guardar en un nuevo array de objetos, cada objeto, con esas tres caracteristicas, ejemplo:

```
let nuevoArray = [
   { titulo: "dark knight",
     director: "christopher nolan",
     url: "https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Dark_Knight"
   },
    { titulo: "inception",
     director: "christopher nolan",
     url: "https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inception"
   },
 { titulo: "memento",
     director: "christopher nolan",
     url: "https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memento"
   },
]
```

Intente con un forEach pero cuando salgo del ciclo se me guarda en el array *solo el ultimo objeto* y me paso lo mismo haciendo un map (quise crear el objeto dentro del map para que se cree un array de objetos y me devuelve solo el ultimo), creo que se esta reemplazando en cada iteracion y lo mismo si quiero.

Y como seria en el caso de si quiero guardar en un objeto en vez de un array? ejemplo

```
 let nuevoObj = {
   miObj1 : [],
   miObj2: []
}
```

(pero esta duda tal vez sea para otra pregunta)

gracias por la ayuda :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Estás cerca, te faltaría leer algo más sobre [map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) o [forEach](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach)

```js
let nuevoArray = [
   { titulo: "dark knight",
     director: "christopher nolan",
     url: "https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Dark_Knight",
     otrascosas: "No importante"
   },
    { titulo: "inception",
     director: "christopher nolan",
     url: "https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inception",
     otrascosas: "No importante"
   },
 { titulo: "memento",
     director: "christopher nolan",
     url: "https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memento",
     otrascosas: "No importante"
   },
]

let arrayObtenido = [];

arrayObtenido = nuevoArray.map( function (elem) {
  let returnObjeto = { titulo: elem.titulo, director: elem.director, url: elem.url };
    return returnObjeto;
});

console.log(arrayObtenido);
```

Con respecto a guardarlo de este modo:

```
let nuevoObj = {
   miObj1 : [],
   miObj2: []
}
```

Indica que propiedad quieres usar en lugar de miObj1, miObj2, y con gusto trataremos de ayudarte.
Pero si quieres usar el título, por ejemplo, tendrías algo de este modo.

```js
let nuevoArray = [
   { titulo: "dark knight",
     director: "christopher nolan",
     url: "https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Dark_Knight",
     otrascosas: "No importante"
   },
    { titulo: "inception",
     director: "christopher nolan",
     url: "https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inception",
     otrascosas: "No importante"
   },
 { titulo: "memento",
     director: "christopher nolan",
     url: "https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memento",
     otrascosas: "No importante"
   },
]

let objetoObtenido = {};

nuevoArray.map(function (elem) {
  let directorYUrl = {director: elem.director, url: elem.url};
  objetoObtenido[elem.titulo] = directorYUrl;
});

console.log(objetoObtenido);
```

De esta manera, por ejemplo para acceder a los datos de la película dark knight, te bastaría con hacer `objetoObtenido["dark knight"].director` u `objetoObtenido["dark knight"].url`

Comment: En la función `map`, puedes ahorrarte poner `director: elem.director`, usando una sintaxis así: `const {director, url} = elem`. De esta manera obtienes la propiedad `director` y `url` de `elem` y en el objeto solo pones `{ dicrector, url }`

Comment: Y también puedo usar arrow functions y hasta hacerlo en una línea, pero para alguien que está aprendiendo, traté de priorizar claridad por sobre todo.

Answer (score 1):

Para lo que necesitas, una de las maneras sin utilizar ciclos `for`, es implementar `map` de esta forma

```
const nuevoArray = tuArrayCompleto.map(({ titulo, url, director }) => ({ titulo, url, director }))
```

Un ejemplo funcional sería

```js
const movies = [
   {
     id: 1,
     titulo: 'El Señor de los Anillos',
     director: 'Peter Jackson',
     year: 2001
   },
   {
     id: 2,
     titulo: 'Interestelar',
     director: 'Christopher Nolan',
     year: 2014
   },
   {
     id: 2,
     titulo: 'Titanic',
     director: 'James Cameron',
     year: 1997
   }
]

const filterArray = movies.map(({ titulo, director }) => ({ titulo, director }))

console.log(filterArray)
```

Con la función `map`, recorres cada elemento de tu arreglo, y extraes las propiedades que necesitas solamente.

Nos comentas si tienes dudas

Comment: espectacular!! gracias por tu tiempo en responder